# How do I get hold of my access logs from CloudControl

Tags: apache, logging, access-log, cloudcontrol

This may seem like a stupid question, but:

If I have an app deployed to CloudControl, how can I download the access logs directly.

Of course I can cctrlapp myapphere/default log access to 'tail' them.

... but I want to download them for off line analysis.

I checked the documentation, but it there is an obvious way I missed it -= can anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: The question is not programming related. Maybe one could ask it on Serverfault, but I guess it is altogether misplaced in the StackExchange sites. Contact user service or their forum.

Comment: @Kay -> I agree, but I only posted as direct by the support page from the company itself: https://www.cloudcontrol.de/dev-center/support which clearly asks us to post here ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to "download" the logs. We only store the last 500 messages.

Comment: Ok, thanks - are there any add-ons that let me suck the access logs somewhere else ?

Comment: Currently not for the access log. The Logentries Add-on only includes the logs produced by the app or the platform.